# Is it correct to consider nonlinear (2-order) differential equations with the term $u(x)u(-x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've obtained the next equation

$ u'(x)+4u''(x)+a \frac{u(x)^2}{x^2}+b \frac{u(x)u(-x)}{x^2}=0$

Can this equation have any solution? (except $u(x) = const * x $ )  Of course, one can try to solve it using Taylor (or Laurent) series. But may be there are some methods to investigate such "non-local" ODE?

Thanks!

Comment: By subbing -x into the equation, and using both equations to cancel that non-linear term, you can turn this into a linear functional equation. Might be a tough solve though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More of a comment than an answer, but it might get you somewhere:

You can use the fact that every real-valued function can be uniquely written as the sum of an even and an odd function (which are symmetric resp. antisymmetric wrt the reflection $x \mapsto -x$). These even and odd functions are given in terms of the original function as
\begin{align}
 u_s(x) &= \frac{1}{2}\left(u(x) + u(-x)\right),\\
 u_a(x) &= \frac{1}{2}\left(u(x) - u(-x)\right).
\end{align}
Adding resp. substracting the original equation from its reflected counterpart (i.e. with the substitution $x \mapsto -x$) gives the following nonlinear system of ordinary differential equations for $u_{s,a}$:
\begin{align}
 4 u_s''(x) + u_a'(x) + \frac{a}{x^2}\left(u_s(x)^2 + u_a(x)^2\right) + \frac{b}{x^2}\left(u_s(x)^2 - u_a(x)^2\right) &= 0, \\
4 u_a''(x) + u_s'(x) + \frac{2 a}{x^2} u_s(x) u_a(x) &= 0,
\end{align}
with the additional info that $u_s(-x) = u_s(x)$ and $u_a(-x) = - u_a(x)$.
This might get you started -- at least it lets you get rid of the nonlocality.